# Why do I need a trailing slash for the root URI in Spring Data Rest?

Tags: spring, spring-data-rest, httpie

I'm using [Spring Data Rest](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/). I can access a resource from the command line using [httpie](https://httpie.org/) with:

```
http :8080/myapp/books
```

but if I try to access the root URI

```
http :8080/myapp
```

I obtain a [302 redirection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3):

```
HTTP/1.1 302 
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2016 13:30:57 GMT
Location: http://localhost:8080/myapp/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

Testing this url in Firefox redirects me to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/` and display correctly the list of resources. If I add a trailing slash with httpie:

```
http :8080/myapp/
```

I obtain the list of resources. Why do I have to add a trailing slash to avoid the redirect? Can someone explain me the logic behind this behavior?

P.S.: I'm running the application with [Spring Boot](https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/), from [STS](https://spring.io/tools).

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is 
 If you add a trailing `/` it will be understood as a resource group but without that trailing `/` we can not say that, the last part of the url `myapp` may be the resource id, so it needs to check for the resource with id `myapp` first if it does not exist then it will take it as a resource bundle/group and redirects by appending `/`. The `/` indicates that the result will be a group, but without slash it will think as a resource with id.
Ex. `users/user` fetching user with id `user`.
    `users/` fetching the set of users. So it will check for the id first if it did not find any resource, then appends a `/` and redirect.

For more info refer the link https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186959/trailing-slash-in-restful-api